# awk file sanity check. awk check for null/missing values in csv files

Tags: awk, csv

I'm trying to write a simple file sanity check script. I have a directory with dozen CSV files containing id,edname,firstname,lastname,suffix,email.

I like to write a awk script to check if first field contain a number and is not empty. and fields number 3,4 & 6 are not empty and that the file contains 6 fields no more no less than 6, if all of this conditions are true nothing happens but if any of these conditions failed, re-name the file to .bad. here is wha i have but is not picking up missing values in columns 4,6.

```
for f in *.csv; do 
  awk -F, '!(NF==6 && $1+0==$1 && $3$4$6!=""){f=1; exit} END{exit f}' "$f" || mv "$f" "$f".bad;
done
```

Comment: Surely `$3$4$6!=""` will return true if at least one of the fields is non-empty. Is that what you really want?

Comment: no. I see. wha I want is, if any of these fields is empty then that's a bad file, because those fields are required/mandatory.

Answer (score 2):

As steeldriver pointed out in the comments, your third test will be true if any of the three fields isn't empty. I assume you actually want something like this:

```
for f in *.csv; do 
  awk -F, '!(NF==6 && $1+0==$1 && $3!="" && $4!="" && $6!=""){f=1; exit} 
            END{exit f}' "$f" || mv "$f" "$f".bad;
done
```

Comment: how can I also check if $6 contains an @ sign?

Answer (score 1):

No need to do string comparisons if you just want to ensure it's not null.  Empty strings are falsy, so:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN {flag=0} !(NF==6 && $1+0==$1 && $3 && $4 && $6) {flag=1} END {exit flag}'
```

Comment: This fails if fields 3, 4 or 6 are `0` though. But that's not empty.

Comment: I believe it fair to infer that a first name, last name, and email address of `0` are invalid, but you also raise a fair point.

Comment: lol, I had completely missed that point. You're right, a last name of `0` doesn't seem very likely :) Ah, but you should also check that `$1` is a number.

Comment: yes $1 must be a number, otherwise is a bad file.